# How can one find the true dip angle and quadrant when an apparent dip and strike is provided?

Tags: geology, structural-geology

I am trying to solve the following question but cannot figure out how: 
A layer of limestone has a strike of East to West on a hilltop, and an apparent dip of 40 degrees on the vertical hillside trending N35E. What is the true dip angle and quadrant?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question to me. Have you asked your peers, or the teacher, or consulted the course material on how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: the apparent dip will always be less than or equal to the true dip. There are a number of ways to approach the calculation, depending on the precision you need. This is essentially a trigonometry problem. Look up how to use fold lines or stereonets